# Google Integrity API For Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How to secure our Xamarin.forms Android app using googles latest Integrety API? I found that there is one binding for Google Play Services library 'com.google.android.play:integrity'. [Xamarin.Google.Android.Play.Integrity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.Android.Play.Integrity/#readme-body-tab).But there is no documentation or anything related to it. How to consume this Nuget and make use of Google integrity API on Xamarin.Forms Android App? Any help is appriciated.

Comment: On the Google API Client Libraries, I only find the [Google Play Integrity API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/playintegrity/v1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had difficulty implementing this too, and finally succeeded without finding too much information/documentation/sample on internet too, I share my "custom" solution here :-)

**Forms project :**

- create an Interface (for Forms Abstraction/DependencyInjection) and a class for your results :

```
public interface IPlayIntegrityService
{
    Task<bool> InitPlayIntegrityAsync();
    Task<List<PlayIntegrityResult>> CheckPlayIntegrityWithDetailsAsync();
}

public class  PlayIntegrityResult
{
    public string VerificationName { get; set; }
    public string VerificationResult { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompliant { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
}
```

**Android project :**

- add Xamarin.Google.Android.Play.Integrity(1.2.0.2) Nuget
- add Google.Apis (1.64.0) Nuget
- add Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1 (1.64.0.3253) Nuget
- create a Android implementation of IPlayIntegrityService (and inject in your DI container at startup)

```
using Android.Gms.Common.Apis;
using Android.Gms.Extensions;
using Android.Gms.Tasks;
using Android.Runtime;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using Xamarin.Google.Android.Play.Core.Integrity;
using platform = Xamarin.Essentials.Platform;
using Tasks = System.Threading.Tasks;

public class PlayIntegrityService : Java.Lang.Object, IOnFailureListener, IOnSuccessListener, IPlayIntegrityService
{
    IStandardIntegrityManagerStandardIntegrityTokenProvider integrityTokenProvider;
    const string requestHash = "myCustomHashInBase64"; // <- your custom Base64Hash (min. 16 car, base64 encoded)
    const string packagename = "my.Package.Identifier"; //<-your android package id
    const string googleAppName = "MyApplicationName"; // <- your android application name
    const double googleProjectNumber = 012345678901; //<-your google cloud project nb
    const string googleJSONCredentials = "YOURJSONCREDENTIALS"; // your Google cloud API JSON credentials
    
    private string responseToken;
    

    public async Tasks.Task<bool> InitPlayIntegrityAsync()
    {
        if (integrityTokenProvider == null)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create an instance of a manager.
                IStandardIntegrityManager standardIntegrityManager = IntegrityManagerFactory.CreateStandard(platform.AppContext);

                //Create "PREPARE" Request
                var request = StandardIntegrityManagerPrepareIntegrityTokenRequest
                    .InvokeBuilder()
                    .SetCloudProjectNumber(googleProjectNumber)
                    .Build();

                // execute "PREPARE" request
                await standardIntegrityManager.PrepareIntegrityToken(request)
                    .AddOnSuccessListener(this)
                    .AddOnFailureListener(this);

                //Wait for tokenProvider (max 15s)
                int nbtries = 0;
                while (integrityTokenProvider == null && nbtries < 15)
                {
                    await Tasks.Task.Delay(1000);
                    nbtries++;
                }

                //wrong init if no token provider has been received during 15 seconds...
                if (integrityTokenProvider == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                //All is prepared correctly !
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Provider already initialized, all is OK
            return true;
        }

    }
    
    public void OnFailure(Java.Lang.Exception e)
    {
        integrityTokenProvider = null;
        Console.Write($"OnFailure : {e}");
    }

    public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        //If we received a "Prepare" response
        try
        {
            var castedresult = result?.JavaCast<IStandardIntegrityManagerStandardIntegrityTokenProvider>();
            if (castedresult != null)
            {
                integrityTokenProvider = castedresult;
            }
            Console.Write("OnSuccess : Received IntegrityTokenProvider !");
        }
        catch {} //Handle the error for not throwing

        //If we received a "Token" response
        try
        {
            var castedresult = (StandardIntegrityManagerStandardIntegrityToken)result;
            if (castedresult != null)
            {
                responseToken = castedresult.Token();
            }
            Console.Write("OnSuccess : Received IntegrityTokenResponse !");
        }
        catch {} //Handle the error for not throwing
    }

    // THIS IS OUR CUSTOM RULES FOR VERIFICATIONS WE WANTED/NEEDED... ADAPT THESE VERIFICATIONS TO YOUR OWN RULES !!!
    public async Tasks.Task<List<PlayIntegrityResult>>CheckPlayIntegrityWithDetailsAsync()
    {
        //Result Initialization
        List<PlayIntegrityResult> results = new List<PlayIntegrityResult>()
        {
            new PlayIntegrityResult() { VerificationName = "PackageName & Hash", IsRequired = true, VerificationResult = "Not evaluated", IsCompliant = false},
            new PlayIntegrityResult() { VerificationName = "Device integrity", IsRequired = true, VerificationResult = "Not evaluated", IsCompliant = false },
            new PlayIntegrityResult() { VerificationName = "Application integrity", IsRequired = false, VerificationResult = "Not evaluated", IsCompliant = false },
            new PlayIntegrityResult() { VerificationName = "GooglePlay licence", IsRequired = false, VerificationResult = "Not evaluated", IsCompliant = false},
            new PlayIntegrityResult() { VerificationName = "PlayProtect state", IsRequired = false, VerificationResult = "Not evaluated", IsCompliant = false }
        };
        try
        {
            if (integrityTokenProvider != null)
            {
                // Request integrity token
                await integrityTokenProvider
                        .Request(StandardIntegrityManagerStandardIntegrityTokenRequest
                                       .InvokeBuilder()
                                       .SetRequestHash(requestHash)
                                       .Build())
                        .AddOnSuccessListener(this)
                        .AddOnFailureListener(this);

                //Wait for Token response (max 15s)
                int nbtries = 0;
                while (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responseToken) && nbtries < 15)
                {
                    await Tasks.Task.Delay(1000);
                    nbtries++;
                }

                //wrong check if no responseToken has been received during 15 seconds...
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responseToken))
                {
                    return null;
                }


                //Need to connect GoogleCloudAPI/PlayIntegrityAPI (it's not the same as PlayIntegritySDK !!! (normaly server-side... but here I consider my android/mobileApp can do everything on its own, withour server side app...)
                GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(googleJSONCredentials);
                var service = new Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1.PlayIntegrityService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = credential, ApplicationName = googleAppName });
                var requestAPI = service.V1.DecodeIntegrityToken(new DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest { IntegrityToken = responseToken }, packagename);
                var result = await requestAPI.ExecuteAsync();
                if (result != null)
                {
                    //We check our custom verifications one by one
                    //PackageName & Hash
                    var requestDetail = result.TokenPayloadExternal.RequestDetails;
                    if (requestDetail.RequestPackageName == packagename && requestDetail.RequestHash == requestHash)
                    {
                        results[0].VerificationResult = "OK";
                        results[0].IsCompliant = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        results[0].VerificationResult = "NOK";
                        results[0].IsCompliant = false;
                    }
                    //DeviceIntegrity
                    var deviceVerdict = result.TokenPayloadExternal.DeviceIntegrity.DeviceRecognitionVerdict;
                    results[1].VerificationResult = JsonSerializer.Serialize(deviceVerdict, options: new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = false });
                    if (deviceVerdict.Contains("MEETS_DEVICE_INTEGRITY") || deviceVerdict.Contains("MEETS_STRONG_INTEGRITY"))
                    {
                        results[1].IsCompliant = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        results[1].IsCompliant = false;
                    }

                    //Application Integrity
                    var AppIntegrity = result.TokenPayloadExternal.AppIntegrity;
                    results[2].VerificationResult = AppIntegrity.AppRecognitionVerdict;
                    if (AppIntegrity.AppRecognitionVerdict == "PLAY_RECOGNIZED")
                    {
                        results[2].IsCompliant = true;
                    }

                    //GooglePlay Licence
                    var AccountDetail = result.TokenPayloadExternal.AccountDetails;
                    results[3].VerificationResult = AccountDetail.AppLicensingVerdict;
                    if (AccountDetail.AppLicensingVerdict == "LICENSED")
                    {
                        results[3].IsCompliant = true;
                    }

                    //PlayProtect
                    var playProtectVerdict = result.TokenPayloadExternal.EnvironmentDetails.PlayProtectVerdict;
                    results[4].VerificationResult = playProtectVerdict;
                    if (playProtectVerdict == "NO_ISSUES")
                    {
                        results[4].IsCompliant = true;
                    }
                    if (playProtectVerdict == "MEDIUM_RISK" || playProtectVerdict == "HIGH_RISK")
                    {
                        results[4].IsRequired = true;
                        results[4].IsCompliant = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write($"Exception during CheckPlayIntegrityWithDetailsAsync ({ex})");
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

And to call this in Forms App, just resolve your instance (depending on your DI container... here I use Shiny...) and just call your needed methods :

```
var PlayService = ShinyHost.Resolve<IPlayIntegrityService>();
if (await PlayService?.InitPlayIntegrityAsync())
{
    var result = await PlayService?.CheckPlayIntegrityWithDetailsAsync();
    if (result != null && result.Count > 0)
    {
        var notCompliants = result.Where(x => x.IsCompliant == false && x.IsRequired == true);
        if (notCompliants != null && notCompliants.Count() > 0)
        {
            var notCompliantDescription = "";
            foreach (var notCompliant in notCompliants)
            {
                notCompliantDescription += string.Join(notCompliant.VerificationName, " : ", notCompliant.VerificationResult, Environment.NewLine);
            }
            await Dialogs?.Alert(notCompliantDescription, "Play Integrity Failed !");
            Logger.LogInformation("GooglePlayIntegrity not compliant : {0}", notCompliantDescription.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " - "));
        }
        else
        {
            isPlayIntegrityOk = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simplified/not best clean sample, and you have to adapt this to your verification needs.
But all this is currently running correctly on my side in a production app (2023/12/07 - X.Forms 5.0.0.2622 - AndroidTargetFrameworkVersion=v13.0)

I Hope this helps ;-)

Jérôme